# WPF-XAML: Images disappear in designer after running

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am creating an application on Visual Studio 16.3 and I have created some buttons with images on them. Everytime I run the application, the image appear in runtime but when I close the build, all the images disapear in the designer and it's very annoying. I have to cut the code that contains the image references and wait around 1 to 2 seconds and paste the code again to make the image reappear. Here is my code:

In my MainWindow, I have created resources so that I can reuse the images:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="Students" UriSource="Resources/Graduate/2x/baseline_student_black_18dp.png"/>        
</Window.Resources>
```

I have created a side menu containing names and images:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewMain" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="ListViewMain_SelectionChanged">
  <ListViewItem Width="128" x:Name="ItemClass" HorizontalAlignment="Left">    
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Margin="5" Source="{DynamicResource Students}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Home" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Foreground="#FF606060"/>
     </StackPanel>
  </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

I have spent a quite amount of time on the internet trying to find out why this is happening but I haven't found anything. Most of the questions are related to images not appearing in runtime while my problem is that my images do not appear in designer.

Might this be related to the fact that I am using .Net Core 3? I know there are a lot of bugs in Visual Studio. Maybe this is one of them.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Try out the VS plugin [Kill the WPF Designer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Johan20D.KilltheWPFDesigner). It was made by a StackOverflow user Johan Larsson. I've had those kind of issues where designer is really _buggy_ and using this, makes it refresh.

Comment: Thanks André, I will give it a look and see if this works. As someone with no background in programming or design, I am wondering if  I should have gone with some other tool insted of VS and C# :s

Comment: I made a test on my side. I tried it on net core 3.0 and NET Framework . It is same as you, the image do not appear in designer view(net core 3.0). So, I suggest you can go to the [Developer Community Visual Studio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) and report this issue.